# Algolia search with a certain category first

Tags: algolia

I'm trying to search Algolia and have results for a certain category show up before all other categories. Here's an example:

**Data in Algolia**

```
{ name: Harry Potter, category: book},
{ name: The Avengers, category: movie},
{ name: Pottery, category: movie}
```

**Problem**

Let's say the normal Algolia algorithm has `Harry Potter` way more relevant than the movie `Pottery`, so normally if you searched `pot` then `Harry Potter` would show up ahead of `Pottery`.

I want to pass Algolia the search term `pot` and the category `movie` and then have `Pottery` show up ahead of everything else. It needs to be dynamic, i.e. I should be able to search `pot` with category `book` and get `Harry Potter` first.

Is there a way to do this with Algolia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a nice way to implement that behavior using "optional" facet filters (a soon to be released advanced feature - as of 2016/12/01).

An "Optional Facet Filter" is a facet filter that doesn't need to match to retrieve a result but that will - by default - make sure the hits that have the facet value are retrieved first (thanks to the `filters` criterion of Algolia's tie-breaking ranking formula).

This is exactly what you want: on every single page where you want some results sharing a `category` value to be retrieved first; just query the Algolia index with the `category:value` optional facet filter.

- make sure your `category` attribute is part of your `attributesForFacet` index setting
- at query time, query the index with `index.search('', { optionalFacetFilters: ["category:book"])`

You can read more on [this (beta) documentation page](https://www.algolia.com/doc/advanced/optional-filters-scoring).

Comment: I have a need for something similar, but even more complex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166479/complex-featured-product-model-using-query-time-ranking-optional-filters Would appreciate any help!