# Complex "featured product" model using query-time ranking (optional filters)

Tags: ranking, facet, algolia

I have a **products** index that displays filtered results on **category** pages.

1. For a given **category**, any amount of **products** may be flagged as **featured**, meaning it displays first.
2. When **products** are displayed for a **category**, only one **featured product** should show at a time (at random from the available products flagged as featured)
3. Additionally, a **product** should not be flagged as **featured** if it has date range fields and the current date is not within the range

So, my index might look something like: https://gist.github.com/1a0327d8a321dc6627e197b94f4209c9

A solution to **1.** has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40922535 using *optional filters*, currently in private beta: https://www.algolia.com/doc/advanced/optional-filters-scoring/. At query time I could do `optionalFacetFilters: ["featuredIn.category:category1"]` **Update:** I've since been told by Algolia reps that this feature is has a large performance cost, and therefor is only really viable for enterprise customers.

However, I'm at a loss as to how to pull of **2.** and **3.**.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've the feeling you will need to perform extra/additional queries (filtered on the date range for instance) and have a bit of frontend logic to decide whether you should display those results or not.

Comment: Do you need the featured product to be always at the top of the results, or should it only be bearing a special element to make it more visible in the page of all results?

Comment: @OlivierLance it needs to show first. I updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @redox I agree, I essentially need to 2 queries and merge them together, I'm just not sure how/if I can still make it function with my facet filters, and not throw off the result #s and pagination counts.